# how to access running threads in java

Tags: java, spring, multithreading

In my project I have a bunch of threads running in background.

```
            DeamonAlert alertDeamon = new DeamonAlert(tenant.getKey());
            DeamonEventTask eventTask = new DeamonEventTask(tenant.getKey());
            Thread firstThread = new Thread(alertDeamon,tenant+"eventDeomon");
            Thread secondThread = new Thread(eventTask, tenant+ "alertDeamon");
            firstThread.start();
            secondThread.start();
```

While running I need to  call each thread instance's at some portions of 
my application (that have already written). How can I achieve this different criteria?

Comment: can you elaborate??did'nt quite get what exactly you want to achieve

Comment: please be little bit more specific and if possible give some sample code

Comment: what do you mean by "call thread instance"? Thread instance is just an object, and cannot be called. Its method can, however. Do you want to call some method of a thread instance? Then just do it.

Answer (score 0):

Depends on what do you mean:

1. If you want to pass data to your threads, you can use a shared object:

   ```
       Statuses statuses = new Statuses();
       DeamonAlert alertDeamon = new DeamonAlert(tenant.getKey(), statuses);
       DeamonEventTask eventTask = new DeamonEventTask(tenant.getKey(), statuses);
   ```

And you can set the values in it from a thread and read it from another. Design the Statuses class for multi-thread usage: Atomic variables / synchronzed methods ...

2. If you want to pass code to threads to be executed, you can use the previous logic with a collection of Runnable instances. But in this situation it's better to use an [ExecutorService](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html). These are designed for this situation, you have N threads and you can pass Runnable/Callable instances to be executed